# HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported after session is expired/logout

Tags: java, spring-mvc, session, spring-security

I have 2 controllers (with methods GET and POST) that are secured through spring-security w/ csrf protection. Both pages work ok when user is logged in.

After user is logged out or session is expired, accessing the GET page redirects to login page. However, accessing the POST page returns 'HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported'. What is required to redirect a POST request to login page instead?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView home() {
    return new ModelAndView("home");
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView homie() {
    return new ModelAndView("home");
}
```

Comment: Can you see which URL cause 405 error and share the controller code for that path?

Comment: @holmis83 This happens for all controllers that accept POST requests.

Comment: I have the same problem with CSRF protection. If the session has expired and I make a POST request I get a 405 error because Spring Security redirects to `/login` with method POST and my Controller method is configured to receive GET request for getting login page. My "ugly" solution adds POST method to Controller method but I thought Spring Security authenticates with POST method...